# Email validation to include numbers in specific place

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I need to validate that the last four characters of an email address are numbers between 0-9, and that the first bits are letters, separated by hyphen, like in this example:

```
lotte-talia-1864@itmoedlo.com
```

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start with a Google search on RegEx to match your use case. Or better, ask ChatGPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with regular expressions. Per mdn docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions) regular expressions are

> patterns used to match character combinations in strings. In JavaScript, regular expressions are also objects.

Basically, you can create a regular expression object and give it a pattern and flags, e.g. `var regExp = new RegExp(/\d/, 'g')` or `var regExp = new RegExp(/\d/g)` or in the simplest form `var regExp = /\d/g`. Now you can use that object to test, match, etc. (read mdn docs) strings.

**For your problem here, you could create a regular expression with the pattern `/\w+(?:-\w+)+/g`.**

- `\w+`: matches any alphanumeric character, meaning every letter from A-Z, a-z, every number and the underscore character `_`, 1 or more times (that's the `+`). Beware, this does not match any other special characters like `? / %` etc, nor any specialized character like `è á` etc.
- `(?:)`: this is a grouping expression `()`, but it doesn't create a capture group `?:`. Can **really** recommend reading into it yourself if you want to fully understand the non-capture group, but for simplicity, just see it as a grouping expression. You can also just use the normal capture-group `()` here, it depends on further needs.
- `-\w+`: this part inside the group is about the same as the `\w+` expression, only difference is the preceding `-` hyphen character.
- `+`: please remember this quantifier after the group `()+`. Taking your example `lotte-talia-1864@itmoedlo.com`, without the `+` it would match `lotte-talia` and with it `lotte-talia-1864`. When testing, it would still say there was a match, but it would not be the match you wanted.
- `g`: the `g` at the end is a flag, to be precise, the global flag, which means that the search for matches doesn't end after the first match is found in a string. In your case, if you're always just testing a string containing one single email, this wouldn't be necessary.

If you want to see what kind of expressions exist, or test regExp patterns, I can recommend https://regexr.com/ or https://regex101.com/. Regexr is a bit simpler and easier on the eyes when starting, in my opinion.

### Edit

Just for clarity, you can use this on the whole email with no problem, it will only match before the `@`, unless there is a hypen after the `@`. But you could split the email into parts and only check the part before the `@` to be extra precise (maybe someone has `word-word` after the `@`), like:

```js
var regExp = /\w+(?:-\w+)+/;

var email = "lotte-talia-1864@itmoedlo.com";

if(regExp.test(email.split("@")[0])) {
  // stuff to do when email matches pattern
}
```

This could also be ignored when using `^` (beginning of string) at the beginning of the pattern, so it would be `/^\w+(?:-\w+)+/g`.

Comment: Thanks... Very helpful. sorry for rubbish question, I'm very new to this

Comment: No problem, I'm quite new as well, I think people here are too harsh with new users and expect them to ask perfect questions from day 1. Anyway, if you have more questions, feel free to ask :)